# Efficiently evaluate a function of an array's values _and_ indices

Tags: python, numpy

For a machine learning project I am doing, I need to transform a 2D array of floats to another array of the same shape where elements to the left and below are at least as large as the given element.

For example,

```py
In [135]: import numpy as np
     ...: A = np.array([[1, 2, 1, 1],
     ...:               [1, 1, 6, 5],
     ...:               [3, 2, 4, 2]])
     ...: print(A)
[[1 2 1 1]
 [1 1 6 5]
 [3 2 4 2]]
```

Because A[0,1] = 2, I the following elements (below and to the right) to be >= 2:  A[0,2], A[0,3], A[1,1].

Likewise, because A[1,2] = 6, I the following elements (below and to the right) to be >= 6:  A[1,3], A[2,2], A[2,3].

I need to do this for every element in the array.  The end result is:

```py
[[1 2 2 2]
 [1 2 6 6]
 [3 3 6 6]]
```

Here's code that works, but I'd rather use fewer loops.  I'd like to use vector operations or apply the function `set_val` against all elements of the array `A`.  I looked into `meshgrid` and `vectorize`, but didn't see how to pass the index of the array (i.e. `row,col`) to the function.

```py
def set_val(A, cur_row,cur_col,min_val):
    for row_new in range(cur_row,A.shape[0]):
        for col_new in range(cur_col,A.shape[1]):
            if A[row_new,col_new] < min_val:
                A[row_new,col_new] = min_val

A_new = A.copy()

#Iterate over every element of A
for row,row_data in enumerate(A):
    for col,val in enumerate(row_data):
        #Set values to the right and below to be no smaller than the given value
        set_val(A, row, col, val)

print(A_new)
```

My question:  Is there a more efficient (or at least more Pythonic) approach?

Comment: Not really related, but don't use global variables.

Comment: You can use `np.maximum.accumulate(np.maximum.accumulate(A), axis=1)`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, good point about the globals.  It's not needed.  I've revised the question to eliminate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of two "cummulative maximum" calls:

```
from np.mx import maximum as mx

mx.accumulate(mx.accumulate(A), axis=1)
```

The `mx.accumulate` calculates the *cummulative* maximum. This means that for `axis=0`, the value for *B = accumulate(A)* is so that *b<sub>ij</sub>=* max<sub>k≤j</sub> *a<sub>ik</sub>*. For `axis=1`, the same happens, but columnwise.

By doing this two times, we know that for the result *R* the value for *r<sub>ij</sub>* will be the maximum of *r<sub>ij</sub>=* max<sub>k≤i, l≤ j</sub> *a<sub>kl</sub>*.

Indeed, if such the largest element exists in this subrectangle, then the first `mx.accumulate(..)` will copy that value to the right, and thus eventually to the same column as the "target". Then the next `mx.accumulate(.., axis=1)` will copy that value to the same row as the "target", and thus pass that value to the correct cell.

For the given sample input, we thus obtain:

```
>>> A
array([[1, 2, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 6, 5],
       [3, 2, 4, 2]])
>>> mx.accumulate(mx.accumulate(A), axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 6, 6],
       [3, 3, 6, 6]])
```

**Benchmarks**: if we run the above algorithm for a random 1000×1000 matrix, and we repeat the experiment 100 times, we get the following benchmark:

```
>>> timeit(lambda: mx.accumulate(mx.accumulate(A), axis=1), number=100)
1.5123104000231251
```

This thus means that it calculates one such matrix in approximately 151 milliseconds.

Comment: Amazing.  I thought my application was unusual, but Numpy had a function that was exactly what I needed.